# File delete Code

Tags: ios, directory, uicollectionview, delete-file

I want to delete pictures using the CollectionView that is getting the photo from the directory folders since I have made sub directory to store the images.

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSLog(@"ray:%d", [Trash count]);
    NSString *trashBin = [Trash objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"k%@l",trashBin);


}
```

This is my code for delete but I have to add the file delete code which I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

I believe below is what you are looking for.

```
NSError *error;
NSString *myFileName;
// this is global variable


-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSLog(@"ray:%d", [Trash count]);
    NSString *myFileName = [Trash objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"k%@l",myFileName);
    [self deleteMyFiles];



}

-(void) deleteMyFiles {
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // Point to Document directory
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() 
         stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];

    NSString *filePath2 = [documentsDirectory 
                             stringByAppendingPathComponent:myFileName];

    if ([fileMgr removeItemAtPath:filePath2 error:&error] != YES)
      NSLog(@"Unable to delete file: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

For more details visit,

http://iosdevelopertips.com/data-file-management/iphone-file-system-creating-renaming-and-deleting-files.html

This link have all examples of actions to do on file.

---

You are getting this because you have not set error.

add `NSError *error;` before `NSError *myFileName;`

```
NSError *error;
NSString *myFileName;
// this is global variable
```

Comment: This deletes the file itself and I just want to delete the one that the user taps Using the path above.

Comment: @Radical : see my updated answer.. hope that is what you want

Comment: Im almost there! `if ([fileMgr removeItemAtPath:filePath2 error:&error] != YES)
        NSLog(@"Unable to delete file: %@", [error localizedDescription]);` I am getting an error of undeclared identifier "error". and also unused variable fileMGR and filepath2

Comment: I am getting an error Unable to delete file: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)